# Taking picture without using Media Intent in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I have to take picture without using Media intent i-e without previewing this camera.How can I do this can anyone help me in this regard.

waiting for your reply
Altaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take a picture without a preview. Whether it is the preview offered by the `Intent` or it is a preview that you create yourself with a `SurfaceView` when you use the `Camera` object, there has to be a preview.

Answer (score 0):

Just use takePicture() directly on the camera object:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture

I believe some of the older devices wouldn't capture correctly unless preview was setup, but I don't think that's an issue any more. And if you are looking to target devices that require preview you can just resize the preview surface to a single pixel somewhere and put another control on top of it. Still eats resources, but shouldn't be visible.